# Properties of open covers of the closed unit n-disk

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Consider a closed $n-$disk and let $\{U_{a}\}_A$ be a finite open cover. Let $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{A'}$ be another finite open cover such that $V_{\alpha_i}\subseteq U_{\alpha_j}$ for all $i$ and some $j.$ (So $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{A'}$ is a refinement of $\{U_{a}\}_A$.)

I am trying to find the following:
$\max_{\{U_{\alpha}\}_A} \min_{\{V_{\alpha}\}_{A'}} \max_{x\in\text{Disk}} |\{\alpha:x\in V_{\alpha}\}|$

My guess is that this equals $n-1$ since that seems to be the answer for dimensions 2 and 3 (via drawing) but I don't have a great way of showing it in general.
I'm pretty sure the *lower* bound is $n-1$ for the same reason that 3 and 4 overlapping sets are needed for dimensions 2 and 3, respectively.

(This was relevant to bounding a degree in the graph of the nerve of a cover for my research, but I realized it doesn't actually solve the overarching problem. I am still curious as to people's thoughts, though)

Comment: You can assume each $U_a$ is a disk, and the notion of covering dimension seems relevant.